# no such method 'add' for tabs widget instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-tabs, razor-2

I am using the jqueryui tab widget.  I am trying to add tabs dynamically.
I get the following error while try to call $('#id').tabs('add',...):
"**no such method 'add' for tabs widget instance**"

I am using ASP.NET MVC.4 - Razor - This is in a partial view.  The layout for the container view includes the correct jquery bundle inclusion:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

I am using jquery v2.0.0 & jquery v1.10.2.

Here is some code that is called during initialization:

```
$('#tSheet').tabs();
$('#tSheet').tabs("add", '', 'Tab test one');
$('#tSheet').tabs("add", '', 'Tab test two');
```

and the html:

```
<div id="tSheet">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Have any ideas as to why I am getting this error?
Thank you,
Jim

After learning that jquery-u1 1.10.2 drops the add method - I replace that code with the following:
Thank you Kevin,

Adding replacing the add with the following the calling refresh causes an different error.

```
$('#tSheet > ul').append('<li><a href="#general">General</a></li>');
$('#tSheet').append('<div id="#general">Some text</div>');

$('#tSheet').tabs('refresh');
```

This causes an exception when I click on the tab.

Comment: The newest version of jQuery UI tabs doesn't have an add method. Instead, add the new tab and tab content yourself and call the refresh method.

Comment: the second line should be:
`$('#tSheet').append('<div id="general">Some text</div>');`
you forget to remove the `#` sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `add` method on jquery ui now. You can read documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

But you can solve your problem by adding html to your content for example with [jquery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function. And then create tabs:

```
$('#tSheet').tabs();
```

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) you can look for example how should html looks.

[Nice jsFiddle example of adding new elements.](http://jsfiddle.net/dsu4z/)

Comment: samples there do not demonstrate adding new tabs, just content.

Comment: @Jim let's look at example which I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I am now having trouble _selecting_ a tab.
I try `$('#tSheet').tabs('select', '#tabs-1');` this works with the latest version of jquery-ui support at the jsFiddle - but does not with version 1.10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Select is now covered by option active i.e. `$('#tSheet').tabs('option','active', 0)` for the first tab.  Use tab number (key) from the tab array in place of the `0` to select (make active) others.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would leave a comment here in case someone else ran into this problem.

Your solution works. I think there is a typo in your code. There should be no # in front of the id for the `div`.

```
$('#tSheet > ul').append('<li><a href="#general">General</a></li>');
$('#tSheet').append('<div id="general">Some text</div>');
$('#tSheet').tabs('refresh');
```

Ideally we wouldnt want to add tabs if one already exists.

```
var elements_ = [];
$('#tSheet > div').each(function(){
    elements_.push(this.id); 
});
if ($.inArray(title, elements_) === -1){ //add the tab here..
}
```